# T-SQL Performance dilemma when looping through a Big table (details inside)

Tags: performance, t-sql

Let's say I have a `Big` and a `Bigger` table.
I need to cycle through the `Big` table, that is indexed but not sequential (since it is a filter of a sequentially indexed `Bigger` table).

For this example, let's say I needed to cycle through about 20000 rows.

Should I do 20000 of these

```
set @currentID = (select min(ID) from myData where ID > @currentID)
```

or

Creating a (big) temporary sequentially indexed table (copy of the `Big` table) and do 20000 of

```
@Row = @Row + 1
```

?

I imagine that doing 20000 filters of the `Bigger` table just to fetch the next ID is heavy, but so must be filling a big (`Big` sized) temporary table just to add a dummy identity column.

Is the solution somewhere else?
For example, if I could loop through the results of the select statement (the filter of the `Bigger` table that originates "table" (actually a resultset) `Big`) without needing to create temporary tables, it would be ideal, but I seem to be unable to add something like an IDENTITY(1,1) dummy column to the results.

Thanks!

Comment: How does the `myData` table fit into this? And i'm going to need to see example data, cause i have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: You need to tell us more about what you are trying to accomplish and in which version of (presumably) SQL Server. It is very likely that you can do it in a single query without the need for a loop.

Comment: There's just 20K items to process and you're having performance issues?

Comment: Your numbers and your subjective conclusions suggest you probably need to get someone involved who understands databases. This is beyond a paragraph or two in Stackoverflow. "Loop through" is a conceptual non-starter for starters.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider finding out how to do your work **set based** instead of **RBAR**.  With that said, for very big tables, you may want to not make a temp table so that you are sure that you have live data if you suspect that the proc may run for a while in production.  If your proc fails, you'll be able to pick up where you left off.  If you use a temp table then if your proc crashes, then you could lose data that hasn't been completed yet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide more information on what your end result is, It is only very rarely necessary to do row-by-row processing (and almost always the worst possible choice from a performance perspective). This article will get you started on how to do many tasks in a set-based manner:
http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Cursors_and_How_to_Avoid_Them

If you just want a temp table with an identity, here are two methods:

```
create table #temp ( test varchar (10) , id int identity)
insert #temp (test)
select  test from mytable

select  test, identity(int) as id into #temp from mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a join will serve your purposes better.

```
SELECT BIG.*, BIGGER.*, -- Add additional calcs here involving BIG and BIGGER.
FROM TableBig BIG (NOLOCK)
JOIN TableBigger BIGGER (NOLOCK)
  ON BIG.ID = BIGGER.ID
```

This will limit the set you are working with to. But again it comes down to the specifics of your solution.

Remember too, you can do bulk inserts and bulk updates in this manner too.